# Delete line without adding to clipboard?

Tags: notepad++

Ctrl-L deletes current line; I use this constantly.

Unfortunately, it also replaces the text that I have already copied.  Is there another shortcut to delete an entire line, but not add the contents to my clipboard?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

You can swap this around in Macro - Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro - Scintilla commands, and then around line 90, there's ones for `SCI_LINECUT` and `SCI_LINEDELETE`

Answer (score 6):

By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> however you can change it to something like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> by going to the **Settings** menu, **Shortcut Mapper**, click on the **Scintilla commands** tab, scroll to **command 90, "SCI_LINEDELETE"** and adjust the shortcut from there. Valid as of Notepad++ 6.9.1. If it changes comment and I'll update my answer. You'd think people would answer with *how* to change a shortcut in a customizable editor?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes to the start of the line, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> deletes to the end of the line. So you could press both in quick succession. Or Home/End and one of the combos.

Comment: `Home, Ctrl+Shift+Delete, Backspace`
or
`Ctrl+L`
Anyone familiar with speed improvement knows that reducing the number of steps is way faster in the long run than being fast at more steps. No matter how fast you are at typing the 5-key combination, eventually you will be even faster at typing the 2-key combo.