# Change keyboard shortcut notepad++ to delete line

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried the suggestions here:

[Delete line without adding to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031741/delete-line-without-adding-to-clipboard)

You are supposed to be able to change the default keyboard shortcut by going to Settings->Shortcut mapper-->Scintilla commands and then at line 90/91 change the keyboard shortcut for delete line, but this didn't work. It only worked to delete a line if it was set to ctrl+L. I would like to map it to shift+delete. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the line you've modified is red. If it's red, then it means that an other function is also mapped to the same key combination so none of them will work.
By default the Shift+Del combo is mapped to the basic Cut function at line 1 in Scintilla config.
You have to remove the conflicting setting from line 1 to make it work.