# Delete Line without changing Clipboard in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I use Ctrl+L to delete a line inside visual studio. It deletes the line but it also puts that deleted line into clipboard.

Anyone know how to avoid that.

This is exactly the same but it is related to notepad++.
[Delete line without adding to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031741/delete-line-without-adding-to-clipboard)

I tried looking into Visual Studio keyboard Bindings, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Looking at the keyboard shortcuts already set (in VS 2019) Edit.LineDelete is mapped to `ctrl`+`shift`+`L`

Comment: You can also use `Shift` + `Delete` to delete a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the keyboard shortcuts already set (in VS 2019) `Edit.LineDelete` is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

If it's not configured in your version, set the shortcut to whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks Mate, Ctrl + L has been mapped to Line Cut. It all makes sense now. 
BTW I am using VS 2019 only.